# @Repository not necessary when implementing JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a repository class in my spring boot app. First, I annotated it with `@Repository` and then I implemented `JpaRepository`. Now I got rid of the annotation and it still works.

I saw that `JpaRepository` has the `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation.

How does this work? Or should this not work and there's something weird going on in my application?

Comment: did u make @EnableJpaRepositories in repositories configuration?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It is indeed not necessary to put the `@Repository` annotation on interfaces that extend `JpaRepository`; Spring recognises the repositories by the fact that they extend one of the predefined `Repository` interfaces.

The purpose of the `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation is to prevent Spring from treating that specific interface as a repository by itself. The `JpaRepository` interface has this annotation because it isn't a repository itself, it's meant to be extended by your own repository interfaces, and those are the ones that should be picked up.

> Or should this not work and there's something weird going on in my application?

It works as it should and there is nothing weird going on in your application.

Comment: Which of the spring data jpa's repository class has @Repository annotation?

Comment: @raj240 None of the classes and interfaces provided by Spring has an `@Repository` annotation. This annotation is meant to be used on interfaces that you define yourself.

Answer (score 7):

It is not mandatory. The reason it will be working is beacause, you would have specified to framework the packages to look for repositories using `@EnableJpaRepositories("packagestoscan")`

Comment: Right, that was it! Thanks!

Comment: This however does not explain how Spring knows that a repository is a repository without the @Repository annotation.

Answer (score 4):

I am gussing you set it up with `@EnableJpaRepositories`. This will scan for `Spring Data repositories` even if they are not annotated with `@Repository`.

From the javadoc:

> Annotation to enable JPA repositories. Will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories by default.

You can also specify `basePackages`/`basePackageClasses` to change the default.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I am still struggling with all the annotations.

Answer (score 4):

When using spring data jpa you don't need to specify repository explicitly. The spring data jpa scans for all interfaces extending repository and generate implementation automatically.

Comment: its comment quality answe

Comment: I realized it after posting. My Bad!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest as a good practice to annotate with @Repository class you are implementing for example:

```
@Repository
JpaRepositoryImpl implements JpaRepository
```

Comment: why though? this makes no sense