# NoClassDeffFoundError: org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using JpaRepository, here is my code

```
public Interface EmpRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {}

class EmployeeServicImpl {

  private EmpRepository empRepository;

  @Autowired
  EmployeeServicImpl (EmpRepository  theRepository) {
    this.empRepository = theRepository;
  }
}
```

added below dependencies in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

While start the application, resolution of declared constructor of bean from class loader : NoClassDeffFoundError : /org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Repository

Comment: The interface `Repository` is indeed in a different package: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html?is-external=true

Comment: Please make sure your imports are correct. If that does not help, please post more of your `pom.xml` and your code.

Comment: post your complete pom.xml

Answer (score -1):

Some points,

1. Keep your repository interface in a separate package.
2. Use `@Repository` on your repository.
3. Use `@Service` or `@Component` annotation at `EmployeeServicImpl` class.

It appears as when you're starting the application, Spring is trying to find `EmpRepository` dependency to instantiate your service but is not able to find the repository since it is not declared as a `@Repository` by you.

Further, reason for using `@Service` is so that `EmployeeServicImpl` becomes available to Spring too.

Comment: Please stop advicing people to use `@Repository` on an Spring Data JPA interface. That is totally useless. Nor will any of this help as his issue is with dependencies in his pom.xml not with the Spring setup.

Comment: Oh ! Something that I didn't know earlier. Thanks for pointing it out, @M.Deinum. I'll not delete the answer to make more dummies be aware of this. [Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069367/repository-not-necessary-when-implementing-jparepository)