# Unable to recognize @Repository in Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, repository

I am getting the below error when trying to run the Spring Boot app.

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field repository in com.javanovice.crud.example.service.ProductService
> required a bean of type
> 'com.javanovice.crud.example.repository.ProductRepository' that could
> not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.javanovice.crud.example.repository.ProductRepository' in your
> configuration.

**ProductRepository.java**

```java
package com.javanovice.crud.example.repository;

import com.javanovice.crud.example.entity.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Integer> {
    Product findByName(String name);
}
```

**ProductService.java**

```java
package com.javanovice.crud.example.service;

import com.javanovice.crud.example.entity.Product;
import com.javanovice.crud.example.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository repository;

    public Product saveProduct(Product product) {
        return repository.save(product);
    }

    public List<Product> saveProducts(List<Product> products) {
        return repository.saveAll(products);
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Product getProductById(int id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Product getProductByName(String name) {
        return repository.findByName(name);
    }

    public String deleteProduct(int id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
        return "product removed !! " + id;
    }

    public Product updateProduct(Product product) {
        Product existingProduct = repository.findById(product.getId()).orElse(null);
        existingProduct.setName(product.getName());
        existingProduct.setQuantity(product.getQuantity());
        existingProduct.setPrice(product.getPrice());
        return repository.save(existingProduct);
    }


}
```

**ProductController.java**

```java
package com.javanovice.crud.example.controller;

import com.javanovice.crud.example.entity.Product;
import com.javanovice.crud.example.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;

    @PostMapping("/addProduct")
    public Product addProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return service.saveProduct(product);
    }

    @PostMapping("/addProducts")
    public List<Product> addProducts(@RequestBody List<Product> products) {
        return service.saveProducts(products);
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> findAllProducts() {
        return service.getProducts();
    }

    @GetMapping("/productById/{id}")
    public Product findProductById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.getProductById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/product/{name}")
    public Product findProductByName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return service.getProductByName(name);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public Product updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return service.updateProduct(product);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.deleteProduct(id);
    }
}
```

**SpringBootCrudExampleApplication.java**

```java
package com.javanovice.crud.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringBootCrudExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootCrudExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }` as follows:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootCrudExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootCrudExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, autoconfiguration will not kick in for Persistence related beans, including the `Repositories`.

Comment: I did that but still getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure you compiled the application again? If you do, can you please add `Product` code to your question? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it. I was using hibernate prefix instead of spring.datasource prefix in application.properties file.Also, no need to add @Repository annotation. Refer the below link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069367/repository-not-necessary-when-implementing-jparepository

Comment: Thanks anyways for responding. Something to learn everyday!

Comment: You are welcome. Either add your solution as an answer and accept it so that the question can be "closed" or delete the question ;) Thanks!